# Using an int pointer to hold address of an array of type int with its index value misunderstanding

Tags: c, pointers

I'm studying some basics in C and I have big problems in understanding pointers, at least to some extent I guess.

This is an example from a book but it doesn't explain it why it is how it is in this case. So:

```
int contestants[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int *choice = contestants;
contestants[0] = 2;
contestants[1] = contestants[2];
//contestants[2] = *choice;
printf("%d\n", *(choice));
printf("%d\n", choice[0]);
printf("I'm going to pick contestant number %i\n", contestants[2]);
```

My question is why, if I uncomment the above line, does it give me a value of `2` and not `3` (the last `printf`). Basically the commented line is the constraint of my grasping this very simple lines, apparently. Thanks

Comment: "*it gives me*" what is "*it*"?

Comment: `choice` points to the array, `*choice` is the first value.
here you set the third value to the first value, so 2

Comment: the last printf i meant by "it", sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int contestants[] = {1, 2, 3};
int *choice = contestants;
```

`choice` points to `contestants`

```
contestants[0] = 2;
contestants[1] = contestants[2];
```

`contestants` is now `2, 3, 3`

`*choice`is the first value so `2`

```
contestants[2] = *choice;
```

contestants is now `2, 3, 2`

Comment: Ni Hao world traveller!

Answer (score 1):

Because `choice` points to `contestants` and

```
contestants[0] = 2;
```

makes the first value of `contestants` 2, so `*choice` dereferences `choice` and it will be pointing at the beginning of `contestants` which  is it's first element and was set to `2`.